# Android SDK licenses

Tags: android, ionic-framework, android-sdk-tools, ionic4

I have error while compile ionic application.

```
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2 not accepted.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 27 in /usr/lib/android-sdk/licenses
Warning: License for package Android SDK Platform 27 not accepted.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':CordovaLib'.
> You have not accepted the license agreements of the following SDK components:
  [Android SDK Platform 27, Android SDK Build-Tools 26.0.2].
  Before building your project, you need to accept the license agreements and complete the installation of the missing components using the Android Studio SDK Manager.
  Alternatively, to learn how to transfer the license agreements from one workstation to another, go to http://d.android.com/r/studio-ui/export-licenses.html

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
/media/skif/4TB-DISK/Projects/ionicProjects/tbApp/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

...

If i check license - all ok:

```
skif@ubuntu-desktop:/media/skif/4TB-DISK/Projects/ionicProjects/tbApp$ ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager --licenses
Warning: File /home/skif/.android/repositories.cfg could not be loaded.         
All SDK package licenses accepted.======] 100% Computing updates...
```

Why am i reciving this error? All licenses accepted. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/1726 said, run `sdkmanager` with parameter `--licenses` will solve this issue.

Note that you have different location of Android SDK your ionic using (`/usr/lib/android-sdk`) and you are using (`~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager`).